# Grails taglib resetting the properties

Tags: grails, taglib

I have the following problem. I've created a TagLibrary which lists the given collection if data as follows

```
    class LisTagLib {

        static final CONTEXT = this.class.name
        /**
         * Current data from collection
         */
        def currentData;
        String columnHeaders = "";
        List writtenHeaders = [];

        // draw main table
        Closure listTable = { attrs, body ->

            def writer = getOut()

            writer << "<table>";
            writer << "<thead>"
            writer << "<tr>"
            writer << columnHeaders
            writer << "</tr>"
            writer << "</thead>"
            writer << "<tbody>"

            if(attrs.source){
                attrs.source.each() { value ->
                    writer << "<tr>";
                    writer << body()
                    writer << "</tr>";
                }
            }

            // output the body
            writer << "</tbody>";
            writer << "</table>";
        } 
.
.
.
}
```

My problem is "columnHeaders" property is not created each time I call this taglib. If I call this as  in page X and then in page Y, page Y also has the headers as "headers shown in page X + headers shown in Page Y". I tried constructor but this class is constructed only once at compile time. What is the solution for this. How can I reset these values each time I call this taglib? 
By the way calling something like

```
columnHeaders = "";
```

in the begining or at the end of the listTable closure Removes the all columnHeaders and no header is printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taglibs are singletons, so class-scope fields like `currentData`, `columnHeaders`, and `writtenHeaders` are shared by all requests. Spring beans default to being singletons, and this is the case in Grails except for controllers which are created per-request and can have state (but shouldn't).

The fix is to move those fields into your tag body as variables and pass them to helper methods as arguments if you need to, instead of referring to them as class fields.

p.s. lose the semicolons :)